# Blockchain receive payments API Network propagation

Tags: blockchain, network, api

I'm using the Blockchain API to generate an address to receive payments. I received a payment to a generated address, then Blockchain sends the received amount to the address I defined but that transaction is never confirmed and has Very Poor network propagation 1% - 7 Nodes.

There is no problem if I'm using Blockchain to manage my wallet but my bitcoin client running on my machine never sees that transaction so my blockchain wallet has 0.86964083 Bitcoins and my local wallet (with the same priv keys) has 0.84787744 Bitcoins due to the poor propagation.

What can I do to propagate the transaction to my bitcoin client?

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark, but perhaps you could get the raw transaction from Blockchain from `http://blockchain.info/rawtx/$tx_hash` and send it from your client with `sendrawtransaction`.